# IMPORTXML Google Sheets Fetch URL Error (Need script trigger help on open only)

Tags: google-apps-script, import, google-sheets, urlfetch, cryptocurrency

My date source is: https://walletinvestor.com/forecast/achain-prediction

On the website they have three main numbers that I am trying to import to my Google spreadsheet (Current Price, 1-Year Forecast, 5-Year Forecast).

In cell C3 I have:

```
https://walletinvestor.com/forecast/achain-prediction
```

My D column is going to be used to import "Current Price" number, my E column is going to be used to import "1-Year Forecast" number, and my F column is going to be used to import "5-Year Forecast" number.

This is the code I am using in D3 to import the three numbers:

```
=arrayformula(regexreplace(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(C3,"//div[@class='col-md-4 col-xs-12 np']//span[@class='bignum']")),"USD",""))
```

About 1% of the time this will work and it will import the numbers that I need, but the majority of the time I get an error of "Can't fetch URL".  I believe this to be because Google Sheets is pulling in the data too frequently.  What I was wondering was, is there a Google Sheets script that I could make to only pull in this data when I open the spreadsheet?  I am scripting illiterate and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to know the situation you are using the fetch, can you show or share us your sample sheet? Of course, please remove your private information. I think that this will help users to think of the solutions and workarounds.

Comment: Here is a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tX_Qcew6kEbE9M3TzglWUKQqY4NdtOa2qPAE9Md_NPw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for sharing the sample sheet. I posted my answer. Please confirm it. If that is not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are 2 patterns for achieving what you want.

### Pattern 1 :

If you want to retrieve values as a custom function, how about this script? When you use this, for example, please put `=fetch(C3)` to `D3`.

#### Sample script 1 :

```
function fetch(url) {
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var values = data.match(/col-md-4 col-xs-12 np\"\>([\s\S]+?)col-md-12/g)[0].match(/\s([0-9.]+)(?=[ |&])/g);
  return [values.map(function(e){return e.trim()})];
}
```

### Pattern 2 :

If you want to retrieve values every time when you open Spreadsheet, how about this script? When you use this, please install a trigger for `onOpen()`.

#### Sample script 2 :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var urls = ss.getRange("C3:C21").getValues();
  var res = [];
  for (var i in urls) {
    var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[i][0]).getContentText();
    try {
      var values = data.match(/col-md-4 col-xs-12 np\"\>([\s\S]+?)col-md-12/g)[0].match(/\s([0-9.]+)(?=[ |&])/g);
      res.push(values.map(function(e){return e.trim()}));
    } catch(e) {
      res.push(["", "", ""]);
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("D3:F21").setValues(res);
}
```

### Note :

- For `https://walletinvestor.com/forecast/funfair-prediction`, `col-md-4 col-xs-12 np` cannot be found in the retrieved data. So the values cannot be retrieved.

  - In this case, I couldn't understand the values you want. I'm sorry.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I tested Pattern 1 and it worked well for me.  Thanks for the solution!